# Pymongo : how to ensure connection and reading from only desired host (especially SECONDARY) in a replica set

Tags: python, mongodb, replicaset, pymongo-3.x

**Background**

mongoDB production cluster (not sharded) 3 hosts. They belong to replica set rs0

- H1 - Primary
- H2 - Secondary
- H3 - Secondary

I am trying to write a ***python*** script using ***pymongo***. This being a production cluster, I want the script to read only from ***H3 secondary replica set*** so as to not burden primary and keep it free for its regular activities. The data will be fetched from a collection called "devices" in the ***batches of 2000 documents***. This should further reduce read operations overhead.

**Relevant Code**

```
client = MongoClient('mongodb://H3-hostname:27017/', replicaset='rs0', readPreference='secondary')
.
.
.
.
.
devices = devices_collection.find({"status" : "ACTIVE"},{"key" : 1, "username" : 1}, sort = [("key", pymongo.ASCENDING)]).batch_size(2000)
```

Also tried creating the client in a little different way by mentioning all the hosts in the cluster as below

```
client = MongoClient('mongodb://H1-Hostname:27017, H2-Hostname:27017, H3-hostname:27017/?replicaset=rs0', readPreference='secondary')
```

**Problem**

As per my understanding, the above client will read ***ONLY*** from the secondary replica set. But when I run the script and look at the cloud manager, H1 which is primary shows page faults increased from ~15-20 to ~600 with a sharp jump.

**Environment**

- Mongo DB 3.0.3 (MMAPv1 storage engine)
- Python 2.7.9
- Pymongo 3.0.3
- OS Amazon Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also posted this problem to mongo-user group, where it was answered.

First of all, the version of pymongo was wrong. It was 2.8, at least the one which python27 was using

```
$ python27
>>> import pymongo
>>> pymongo.version
    '2.8'
```

and

```
$ python
>>> import pymongo
>>> pymongo.version
    '3.0.3'
```

The appropriate syntax for that was

```
MongoClient('mongodb://H3-Hostname:27017/?readPreference=secondary')
```